# Receiving error '__variables_definition:57: bad option: -n' when changing directory in Zsh terminal

Tags: macos, unix, terminal, zsh

In my `zsh` terminal on OSX, I receive the error `__variables_definition:57: bad option: -n` twice in a row whenever I use `cd` and when I first open the terminal. I tried Googling the error, and received no results. I'm hoping it looks familiar to someone on here. I was told to see if `cd` was aliased to anything, but by typing `alias`, it doesn't appear to be.

This doesn't seem to be causing any actual problems, it's just a slight annoyance and I'd like to know what's causing it.

[image]

Comment: Could the down voter explain the down-vote?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like the `chpwd` hook is set to a script with an error.

This hook is called everytime the working directory is changed. There are two ways to set this hook:

1. by setting defining the a function named `chpwd`. To check this run `whence -c chpwd`. It will either return the function body or "chpwd not found"
2. by defining an array with the name `chpwd_functions`, which contains a list of functions that are to be called. Run `echo $chpwd_functions` to get the list and then `whence -c name` for each name to get the function bodies (or just `for func in $chpwd_functions; do whence -c $func; done` to do it in one go).

Most likely here it is the second case and the culprit is a function named `__variable_definition`. In the 57th line of this function there is a faulty call to a command which does not know the option `-n`. Considering the name of the surrounding function it is probably `typeset` or one of its equivalents `declare`, `float`, `integer`, `local` or `readonly`.

You will have to look in your zsh configuration where `__variable_definition` is defined and fix the error there.

**Note**: the output of `whence -c name` is not always entirely identical to the definition of the function as - among other things - empty lines are removed. As the line number in the error message refers to the original definition (including empty lines) the numbering may be off compared to the output of `whence -c name`.

Comment: Thank you. Using `whence -c __variables_definition`, I found that it was an RVM function. I had trouble figuring out how to fix the error within the function, so I just reinstalled RVM, which solved the problem.